# VirtualBox Ubuntu guest can't access company websites e.g gitlab or jenkins when not on the company network but windows 10 can

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

So I have recently setup a new development machine for work, I don't always work in the same office so I have no-proxy access when using Windows 10 for things like our gitlab or jenkins.

The problem is I develop on a Ubuntu virtual machine (we're not allowed to dual boot or install ubuntu on the machine itself). When on Ubuntu I have general internet access but can't access our gitlab, jenkins etc.

I have been searching for a way to share the network between windows and ubuntu but I am not sure if this is even correct and I haven't had any luck getting any access on my ubuntu other than general internet.

Can someone point me in the right direction of what I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You should consult your IT department about this. They have all the details.

Comment: If you are allowed you can try [bridged networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) in that VM. But asked for permission first.

Comment: I am already using a bridge connection